# Spring Boot - dados iniciais para teste

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring, spring-boot

Estou tentando passar dados para testar o front, mas o controller não está recebendo os dados que o Spring Boot deveria iniciar.

Meu application.properties:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Meu import.sql:

```
INSERT INTO convidado
    (id, nome, quantidadeDeAcompanhante)
VALUES(1, 'Pedro', 2);
INSERT INTO convidado
    (id, nome, quantidadeDeAcompanhante)
VALUES(2, 'Ana', 5);
INSERT INTO convidado
    (id, nome, quantidadeDeAcompanhante)
VALUES(3, 'Ricardo', 1);
```

Meu controller:

```
@Controller
public class ConvidadosController {
    @Autowired
    private Convidados convidados;
    @GetMapping("/convidados")
    public ModelAndView listar() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("ListaConvidados");
        modelAndView.addObject("convidados", convidados.findAll());
        System.out.println("***** " + convidados.findAll().toString() + " *******");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Minha Entity Convidado:

```
@Entity
public class Convidado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private Integer quantidadeDeAcompanhante;
```

Meu repository:

```
import com.gestaofestas.model.Convidado;
public interface Convidados extends JpaRepository<Convidado, Long> {

}
```

Minhas pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso está retornando um array vazio e não dá erro. Como faço para testar desta forma, inserindo dados no arquivo sql que o Spring Boot carrega no Hibernate?

Comment: na verdade o nome que ele vai mapear pra fazer esse insert é o "data.sql" não import.sql, checar  sessão 10.3 do manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucao:

1. Coloque o seguinte no seu application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

2. Renomear o arquivo *import.sql* para *data.sql*
3. Certifique que o arquivo *data.sql* está localizado em src/main/resources
4. Coloque `@Column` em cima das variáveis/colunas *nome* e *quantidadeDeAcompanhante*
5. Se vc possuir um script de criacao das tabelas, o script tem que se chamar *schema.sql*. Daí, coloque o seguinte no seu application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Veja mais informacoes na referencia [Database initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) do Spring.

Comment: Não possuo um schema.sql. Continua com não chegando nada no array. Olhando o print da hierarquia de pacotes, acha que pode ser isto? Tá dando: 
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Everton/Documents/gestao-festas/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO convidado (id, nome, quantidadeDeAcompanhante) VALUES(1, 'Pedro', 2); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "QUANTIDADEDEACOMPANHANTE" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO convidado (id, nome, quantidadeDeAcompanhante) VALUES(1, 'Pedro', 2) [42122-200]

Comment: @EvertonLevi JPA nao pode encontrar as colunas do BD. Coloque @Column em cima das variáveis/colunas  ```nome``` e ```quantidadeDeAcompanhante```. Se o erro persistir, crie o arquivo schema.sql e use ```CREATE TABLE...``` para criar a estrutura de sua tabela.